# Python: search a list of numbers in a list of very large numbers, allowing + or - 5 error

Tags: python, list, search, match

Situation:

I want to do a matching: check if a number is in a list of numbers (very large list, length over 1e^5 or even 2e^5) allowing + or - 5 error

Example:
match 95 in list [0, 15, 30, 50,60,80,93]  -> true
match 95 in list [0,15,30,50,60,70,80,105,231,123123,12312314,...] -> false

ps: list are not sorted (or I can sort it if in that way the efficiency can be increased)

I tried to use dictionary (somekey, and list of numbers) but it was too slow when I do the search in the list.

Is there any better ideas? (there are 3000+ of numbers I need to search)

Comment: When you say search, do you mean single to many results, one to one results, or many to many results?
E.G.  you search for 15 in the list of {10 15 20 25 30}.  Do you return the first found, 10, or do you return all found?  Using the last example, let's say you also search for 10 after 15, do you return 10 again?

Comment: You mean you need to search 3000 times on the same list?

Comment: Are your numbers integers or floating-point? What result are you looking for - just `True` or `False` for each search number, or the matching value? If a search number matches more than one target, do you have any preference (ie do you want closest matches, or any match)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do many searches, you can simply create a set and search in that

```
>>> L = [0, 15, 30, 50,60,80,93]
>>> S = {i+x for i in L for x in range(-5, 6)}
>>> 95 in S
True
```

Creating the `set` is O(n) of course, but now lookups are O(1)

Answer (score 5):

**Without sorting your list (O(n) time)**:

```
def search(L, x):
    for i in L:
        if -5 <= i-x <= 5:
            return True
    return False
```

**With sorting (O(nlogn) time to sort + O(logn) time to search)**:

```
def search(L, x):
    L.sort()
    return fuzzyBinSearch(L, x)

def fuzzyBinSearch(L, x):
    mid = len(L)/2
    i = L[mid]
    if if -5 <= i-x <= 5:
        return True
    elif i-x > 5:
        return fuzzyBinSearch(L[mid+1:], x)
    else:
        return fuzzeBinSearch(L[:mid], x)
```

Comment: It would be even better if you can change 5 to a constant like `ACCEPTABLE_ERROR = 5` defined outside `fuzzyBinSearch`.

Answer (score 1):

I like @inspectorG4dget 's answer, but would invert it:

instead of sorting the long list and searching through it (and having to keep it all in memory),

sort the short list (of numbers you are looking for) then iterate through the long list, seeing if each item matches any of the search terms.

This should be both faster and use less memory. You may wish to use Python's `bisect` module to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = set([0, 15, 30, 50,60,80,93])
def match(n):
    return bool({n+i for i in range(-5,6)} & a)
print match(95)

a = set([0,15,30,50,60,70,80,105,231,123123,12312314])
print match(95)
```